# Can the mysql slow query log show milliseconds?

Tags: mysql

The [mysql slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html) shows query time in whole integers.

```
# Query_time: 0  Lock_time: 0  Rows_sent: 177  Rows_examined: 177
SELECT ...
# Query_time: 1  Lock_time: 0  Rows_sent: 56  Rows_examined: 208
SELECT ...
```

There was a [microsecond patch](http://hackmysql.com/microsecond_slow_logs) to allow mysql to be configured to log queries that take longer than X microseconds to run. But is there a way to have the log output the query time in either milliseconds or microseconds?

Comment: what version of mysql? This is built into 5.1.21 and above, and is logged as microseconds. I just confirmed it is working on my 5.1.40 instance.

Answer (score 1):

try this: [Slow Query Log Extended Statistics](http://askmonty.org/wiki/Manual:Slow_Query_Log_Extended_Statistics)